# Have multiple text Layers in CS5

Tags: text

I want to make multiple text Layers in CS5 be able to change the word example "pete" in all the layer at once to "john" is this possible?

Comment: CS5 what??? There are no less than 10 Creative Suite 5 applications.

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator, Photoshop and InDesign all you have to do is Edit > Find & Replace. (In Photoshop its Find & Replace Text)

Find "Pete" Change to "John" choose Replace All